# after filtering a plucked laravel collection, the indexed array change to Associative array

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a collection of model eloquent such as `user` model, i use the `pluck` method to get the only `post_id`from this collection, this method give me the `indexed array of post_id`, but when i use `filter or unique` method for this `indexed array` the result change to `Associative array`. i don't want a `assoc array` in result. I want just the unique of post_id's in the `indexed array`. laravel auto changing my result.

```
$this->posts->pluck('post_id')->unique('post_id')
```

result is :`{ "1": 1 , "2": 2  }`.

Is this can a bug or I have a mistake in fetching data by methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupBy` like this :

```
$this->posts->groupBy('post_id')->pluck('post_id');
```